# How to display a message on a particular hovered card?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have three cards  when I hover on any card it it should translate upwards up to this it's working fine, now what my requirement is when ever the hovered card translates there should be a small space in that I want to fill with some message. Please help me to achieve this thing.

**Note** - each card contains different messages

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
.heart-icons {
  margin-left: -40%;
}


/* .fas{
  background: transparent;
  color:red;
} */

button {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.fas {
  /* padding-left:2000%; */
  background: #ebf5fc;
  padding-top: 500%;
  color: yellowgreen;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* top:10;
  right:50; */
}

audio {
  margin-top: 40%;
}

* {
  margin: o;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  /* background:#c7c744; */
}

#my_audio {
  margin-top: -40%;
}

.main-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #ebf5fc;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.container .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 440px;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset -5px -5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), -5px -5px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 30px;
}

.container .card .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: #ebf5fc;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card:hover .box {
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #b95ce4, #4f29cd);
}

.container .card .box .content {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container .card .box .content h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 8em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.container .card:hover .box .content h2 {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.container .card .box .content h3 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: #777;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card .box .content p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .card:hover .box .content h3,
.container .card:hover .box .content p {
  color: #fff;
}

.container .card:hover .box .content p {
  font-style: italic;
  color: gold;
}

.container .card .box .content a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background: #03a9f4;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container .card:hover .box .content a {
  background: #ff568f;
}

#i1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#love {
  color: red;
}

#shape {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-top: -12%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: where do you want the text  ?  be specific

Comment: I point out in the picture please look at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to use an absolute div to position it on the bottom of the card, next use z index in order to move the absolute div behind the main moving card

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<title>Special-Wishes </title>
<style>
.secret{
position : absolute;
bottom : 2px;
padding : 20px;
z-index : 0
}
.box{
z-index:1
}
</style>
<script>
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>kitty <span class="wifey">puppy</span></h1>
<img id="shape"src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2f/9d/95/2f9d9562eb2252ae132b4bf8258aa18a.jpg"/>

<audio  autoplay id="player">
  <source src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=11wfYWiukbIZJQnDL385jQs2SGQA5ESbL" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ka-f.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/free.min.css?" />
<button id="music" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">
  <i style='font-size:24px;' class='fas'>&#xf7a6;</i>
</button>

<div class="main-section">
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <h2 id="initial">I</h2>
        <h3>Card One</h3>
        <p>Your birthday is the first day of another 365-day journey. Be the shining thread in the beautiful tapestry of the world to make this year the best ever.</p>
     <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="secret">
     This is my secret
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <h2><span class="heart-icon" style='font-size:180px;'>&#9829;</span></h2>
        <h3>Card Two</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni veniam ipsa harum aut dicta! Nesciunt beatae ad sint officia veritatis a incidunt sed sapiente sequi sunt, eos, voluptatem itaque necessitatibus!</p>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>U</h2>
        <h3>Card Three</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni veniam ipsa harum aut dicta! Nesciunt beatae ad sint officia veritatis a incidunt sed sapiente sequi sunt, eos, voluptatem itaque necessitatibus!</p>
        <a href="#">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</div>

</body>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
.heart-icons{
  margin-left:-40%;
}
/* .fas{
  background: transparent;
  color:red;
} */
button{
  border: none;
  position:absolute;
  
}
.fas{
  /* padding-left:2000%; */
  background:#ebf5fc;
  padding-top:500%;
  color:yellowgreen;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* top:10;
  right:50; */
}
audio{
  margin-top:40%;
}
*{
  margin: o;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'poppins',sans-serif;
/* background:#c7c744; */
}
#my_audio{
  margin-top:-40%;
}
.main-section{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background:#ebf5fc;
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 40px 0;
}
.container .card{
  position: relative;
  width:320px;
  height:440px;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
              inset -5px -5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5),
              5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.05),
              -5px -5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
              border-radius: 15px;
              margin:30px;
}
.container .card .box{
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  right:20px;
  bottom:20px;
  background: #ebf5fc;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card:hover .box{
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#b95ce4,#4f29cd);
}
.container .card .box .content{
  padding:20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .card .box .content h2{
  position: absolute;
  top:-10px;
  right:30px;
  font-size: 8em;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
  transition: 0.5s;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.container .card:hover .box .content h2{
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
.container .card .box .content h3{
font-size:1.8em;
color: #777;
z-index:1;
transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card .box .content p{
  font-size:1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #777;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.container .card:hover .box .content h3,
.container .card:hover .box .content p{
  color: #fff;
}
.container .card:hover .box .content p{font-style: italic;color: gold;}

.container .card .box .content a{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  background: #03a9f4;
  margin-top:15px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.container .card:hover .box .content a{
  background: #ff568f;

}
#i1{
width:100%;
height:50px;
}
h1{
text-align:center;
font-size:65px;
font-style: italic;
}
#love{
color:red;
}
#shape{
width:150px;
height:150px;
border-radius:50%;
margin-left:45%;
margin-top:-12%;
}
.
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: If I place second message for second card , for that how to display that message when hover on a particular card

Comment: it didnt work ?